# Should I use sleep timers in PHP scripts when dealing with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, timer, delay

I have a few fairly large PHP / MySQL scripts that is reading and writing to the database thousands of times.

```
9000 * (3 Queries + (3 Queries * # of nested children recursively) )
```

to be specific.

I was wondering if it would be advantageous to put s sleep() in my script for every X number of requests sent to the MySQL query.

Would that help it take a break and process faster or is this a dumb idea?

Thanks

Comment: php executes in serial mode, not parallel, so putting sleeps it not going to speed things up (only slow down with exactly the sleep you add).

Comment: It is also possible that the sleep timer that you add might increase the script execution time which may be more than the PHP limit and the script execution may not complete because of that.

Comment: Sleep, no. Seems to me though that you could probably get that number of queries down though. For example importing large amounts of data you can load "infile" or even combine multiple inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally best to run queries as aggressively as your server can handle without impacting other users of the same system. If you're causing excessive server load, start thinking about adding delays in your code, sleep-based or otherwise.

Normally this isn't an issue.